# Visual Studio Code auto activate python venv when open integrated terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I have difficulty related with Python virtual environment in visual studio code for Windows

I have create new project and add virtual environment with the following command `python -m venv venv`

In `.vscode\settings.json` I add the following line

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
```

After restarting VS Code - Reopen project and reopen terminal, virtual environment still not starting.
I need to run `venv\Scripts\activate` to enable python virtual environment

Am I doing something wrong in the `settings.json` for enabling virtual environment?

I try to change terminal from default terminal to power shell and still not working

Comment: Did you try to configure it using:
CTRL + SHIFT + P: Python select interpreter ?

Comment: @J. Doem Have you installed the Python Extension?

Comment: I have done both and still not working. Found a solution by adding empty `requirements.txt` file

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are trying to make the integrated terminal in VSCode work with your current set environment in Python extension.

Please note they are two separate things: the python.xxx settings configure the debug sessions when you F5 on python codes, while the integrated terminal is a standalone environment outside of your VSCode. You can imagine you have your VSCode open and then separately have a PowerShell terminal open on the side.

This is why

> "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true

didn't apply to the integrated terminals.

To make it work, I took a look at the

> Anaconda Powershell Prompt (Anaconda3)

And the below configuration worked for me, when added to settings.json:

```
 "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
 "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "args": [
        "-ExecutionPolicy",
        "ByPass",
        "-NoExit",
        "-Command",
        "& 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1'; conda activate 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3' "
      ]
    }
  },
```